# finding index in array in mule dataweve 4

Tags: xml, mule, dataweave

Dataweave : Need to find the index of the maximum value of an array and map a particular element from that index.

```
        <row>
           <code>3</code>
           <percentage>0.9723</percentage>
        </row>
        <row>     
           <code>4</code>
           <percentage>0.0278</percentage>
        </row>
        <row>     
           <code>5</code>
           <percentage>0.0123</percentage>
        </row>
```

Example : I want to navigate to each row and find the index of the maximum value of percentage and then map the code value from that index

Answer (score 3):

I added a wrapper element called rows to make it a valid xml then you can get the max element using

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.rows.*row maxBy ((item) -> item.percentage)
```

Comment: Actually I need to map the field "code" where the percentage is maximum.

Comment: You should amend the original answer to clarify that.